# Same SSID different APs and MAC address filtering

Tags: wireless-router, wifi-configuration, mac-address, ssid, wireless-extender

I have one router and one Wi-Fi extender.
The extender is only used to convert Wi-Fi to Ethernet to my desktop PC.
Therefore I don't need the Wi-Fi signal from the extender, but the extender does not have an option to turn the extended Wi-Fi off or change the SSID or the password. So now I have one SSID with two APs.
To prevent clients automatically connect to the extended Wi-Fi, I turned on MAC address filter on the extender and set it to "deny all MAC addresses".

So far the clients work well, they just automatically connect to the router.
Just being curious, will the clients try to connect to the extender periodically and repeatedly when the extender's Wi-Fi signal is stronger?
Or is there some mechanism that can remember and stop to try to connect to it after few times of denials?
I would like to learn about if this setting has some downsides, e.g. phone's batteries will consume faster etc..
Any idea would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is not a wireless mesh (and it does not appear to be) devices will normally connect to the strongest  signal.

But then they often do not automatically disconnect and connect to another point. There is a certain amount of manual connect / disconnect activity involved.

Short of a mesh, I do not know of anything that will correct this.

Try to keep phones near the appropriate access point. I know it can wear down batteries trying to connect.

Different SSIDs (not always convenient) is one way to gain control, because otherwise the connection point used cannot reliably be predetermined.

Comment: Thank you! It is not a wireless mesh. If the extender's signal is way stronger but has a MAC address filter which deny all devices, the devices will have to connect to the weaker AP and will not retry to connect until Wi-Fi off/on?

Comment: That is what I thought, but I have some installations like yours and devices may try the weaker or stronger AP but not always. It cannot be predetermined except to have different SSIDs (not always convenient).